# Liferay plugin package dependencies and Maven

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, liferay, spring-portlet-mvc

I'm starting to develop a `Spring-MVC` `Portlet` project. I did all the configuration needed in `portlet.xml` and `web.xml` but still a little bit confused about the Spring dependencies that have been declared in `liferay-plugin-package.properties`. In fact, should I add the required dependencies in this file and declare them as provided in the project `pom.xml`? 
I use **Maven** as the build and dependency management tool and all examples I've found are based on the **ANT** project. 
How does Liferay is processes the dependencies declared in `liferay-plugin-package.properties` ?
Besides, a maven compile fails since it does not find Spring MVC libraries required for the Spring MVC portlet project. What do you think is missing (or) incorrect in the configuration to create Spring MVC portlet ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go about this is to use the Maven Archetype that's been provided by liferay.

The Maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.liferay.maven.archetypes</groupId>
<artifactId>liferay-portlet-spring-mvc-archetype</artifactId>
<version>6.2.10.15</version>
```

Install this archetype in your local repository and then create a Maven project from this archetype.
This will have all the prerequisites needed for your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... However, it is mandatory to use another archetype (an entreprise one).. So, now I do not know how to do for dependencies like spring-web-servlet, spring-web-portlet that are provided by liferay but can not find them on maven central repo

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily to put any dependencies into liferay-plugin-package.properties file. All you need for your Spring MVC Portlet project should be presented in the project pom.xml file.

All dependencies are accessible from maven repo, e.g. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc-portlet